# What is javascript or jQuery equivalent to Flash/AS3 loadVariablesNum()?

Tags: php, javascript, html, actionscript-3, flash

I'm converting some Flash on a site into Javascript/HTML -- there are some sections where it's calling PHP on a server and then processing the returned results with loadVariablesNum() --

```
loadVariablesNum("../flash_loadtext.php?id="+_root.curId,0);
```

The server returns text such as

```
%27Rizzo+Residence%27+by+Desai%2FChia+Architecture%3B+two+Marc+Jacobs%27+fashion+stores+in+London+and+Atlanta+by+Stephan+Jaklitsch+Design%3B+and+th
```

How can I process this in javascript (jQuery?) to make it useful for HTML/CSS?  That is, what is a Javascript (jQuery?) equivalent to loadVariablesNum() ?

Thanks

Comment: You're looking for AJAX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to "translate" this into the jQuery.ajax() syntax.

It looks like the response that comes back from the server is URI encoded somehow, so in the success callback you would have to decode that to use it in your page.

your call would turn into something like this (very simplified) in jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
   url : "../flash_loadtext.php?id="+_root.curId,
   dataType : html,
   success : function(data) {
    // do your magic with the returned value here..
   }
});
```

Comment: Thank you -- I knew it was an .ajax call but not the 'html' spec -- nonetheless I'm still getting back all sorts of weird characters in the one long string the call returns.  That was really my question: what sort of processing loadVariablesNum() does to the text, why I'm getting all these weird characters and how to parse into html, which is what I think I'm getting.  I have someone working on the php side so I think we'll simply rewrite the php, but it would have been nice to somehow parse what's already coming out...

Comment: If you're working with the backend guys already that would be the easiest. To use what is there, try the decodeURI function (takes a string as it's input) to see what comes out, because the data looks URI encoded. Example : decodeURI(data)